# Trying to return a string from a queue in C/free problems

Tags: c, string, malloc

I've been working on a lab for a CSC class for a while, and unfortunately I'm a bit rusty with C (as you'll probably notice from the code).  I'm encountering two particular problems, both related to memory management.

1) In the dequeue operation, I'm attempting to return a string value from the node at the end of the queue.  Since I'm also trying to use free() and kill off that node once I retrieve the data, I need to use a method like strcpy() to grab the data.  The program segfaults whenever I try to use strcpy, and Valgrind claims invalid r/w.

2) dequeue also is not properly updating the stringQueue struct for reasons I cannot understand.  I have similar code for stacks where the alterations persist, but I can keep running dequeue all day and it won't actually remove the end node.

The relevant code:

```
typedef struct node { 
  char data [strMax];
  struct node * next;
} queueNode;

typedef struct {
  queueNode * head;
  queueNode * tail;
} stringQueue;

char * dequeue(stringQueue *queue) {
  char * data = malloc(strMax * sizeof(char));
  if(empty(*queue)) {
    return "Null list!";
  }
  else if(!(queue->head)->next) { // One item in the queue.
    data = (queue->head)->data;
    //free(queue->head);
    queue->head = NULL;
    queue->tail = NULL;
  }
  else { // Multiple items in the queue.
    data = (queue->tail)->data;
    free(queue->tail);
    queueNode * trace = queue->head;
    while(trace->next) // Seek the last node in the queue.
      trace = trace->next;
    queue->tail = trace;
  }
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that creates a `queueNode`?

Comment: Have updated my answer with your queueing function from your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is in lines like `data = (queue->head)->data;`. You can't assign array like this. you should `memcpy`. (`strcpy` is for null-terminated strings, and I guess that it's not so)

edit: you can also use `strncpy`, to avoid buffer-overflow.

Comment: Just remember that strncpy may not copy the trailing 0-byte if the string is longer than "n", so you may have to add it yourself.

Comment: Thanks!  The string being passed in (in this particular case) is "Utilities," passed in as a direct argument from a test case.  From what I remember it would still be null-terminated, but I'll give memcpy a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to declare `data` as a `char * = NULL` at first. Then when you want to return it use `data = asprintf("%s", (queue->tail)->data);`. That will only do the string allocation and copying when needed, and only the required size. Then your calling code **must take responsibility** for freeing that data itself.

You currently have a `char[]` in your node struct in memory on the heap. Later on, you are setting a pointer to the `data` member of the struct, then freeing the struct in memory. You are left with a 'dangling pointer' that points to where the struct used to be. Trying to use that pointer will end in almost certain doom (or worse, unpredictable behaviour).

Comment: Thanks: as far as altering the char[], that segment is part of the shell we're given and I don't believe I can touch that.  Is there any workaround using the current format?

Regarding the dangling pointer, when free() is uncommented I've been trying to use strcpy(data, (queue->tail)->data but I get an immediate segfault.  Any ideas on what might cause that?

Comment: Is it a null terminated string? As you know the max length of the string, I would say always use strncpy. The segfault might be because it walks off the end of the string due to a missing `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems with your code...

First you do not test that your `queue` argument is not `NULL`. Then you haven't included your definition of `empty()` but probably testing that queue->head is NULL should tell you that the list is empty. Here you are dereferencing it prior testing it's a valid pointer, very dangerous.

Secondly, you are mallocing some data which is not used properly. When you do the affection `data = (queue->head)->next;` you are loosing the pointer to your allocated memory, you probably want to do a `strncpy()` here like `strncpy(data, queue->head->data, strMax)`. After this you can uncomment your `free()`. The function calling your dequeue one will have to `free()` that string later when it's not used anymore.
Why not allocate your `data` only when you are sure that the list is not empty? If you do not want to do this, you then have to `free()` that unsuded malloc'ed memory.

See the code below.

```
queueNode* find_before_tail(stringQueue* queue)
{
   queueNode* node = NULL;

   if (!queue || !queue->head)
      return NULL;

   node = queue->head;
   while (node->next != queue->tail && node->next)
      node = node->next;

   return node;
}

char * dequeue(stringQueue *queue) {
  char *data = NULL;
  queueNode* to_queue = NULL;

  if(!queue || !queue->head) {
    /* Nothing to dequeue here... */
    return NULL;
  }

  data = malloc(strMax * sizeof(char));
  if (!data) {
    printf("Error with malloc()...\n");
    return NULL;
  }

  /* Only one element */
  if(!(queue->head)->next == queue->head) {
    strncpy(data, queue->head->data, strMax);

    free(queue->head);

    queue->head = NULL;
    queue->tail = NULL;
  }
  else {
    strncpy(data, queue->tail->data, strMax);

    to_dequeue = queue->tail;

    queue->head = queue->head->next;

    queue->tail = find_before_tail(queue);
    if (!queue->tail)
       return NULL;
    queue->tail->next = NULL;

    free(to_dequeue);
  }

  data[strMax - 1] = 0;

  return data;
}
```

There are probably some other issues with the rest of your code, judging by this one but hopefully it gives you some basis.

**EDIT WITH YOUR QUEUE CODE**

Here again you are not testing the return value of `malloc()`. Here is a version with a non-cyclic linked list (I've also updated the `dequeue()` function above to work with this).

```
int enqueue(stringQueue *queue, char *item)
{
   queueNode * newNode = NULL;

   if (!queue || !item)
      return EINVAL;

   newNode = malloc(sizeof(queueNode));
   if (!newNode) {
      perror("malloc()");
      return errno;
   }

   strncpy(newNode->data, item, strMax);
   newNode->data[strMax - 1] = 0;

   if (!queue->head) {
       /* Element is queue and tail */
       queue->tail = newNode;
   }

   newNode->next = queue->head;
   queue->head = newNode;

   return 0; /* Everything was fine */
}
```

I have not tested the code but it should be very similar to this. In this scenario, when you have only one element, `this_element->next` is `NULL` and not pointing to itself.

Comment: Thanks-- this was very helpful.  But could you explain EINVAL?  It's been a while since I've looked at C, but I do not ever recall seeing EINVAL.

Comment: EINVAL is a predefined C Macro for returning error codes in a standard way. I recommend you take a look at http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno, it describes standard error code. Please understand that you could have returned any value as long as you document it and you do the right thing in the caller function.